# How to pass button value from partial to parent view using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have created a partial and parent view where I want to pass `raceid` value from partial to parent view. I tried this code but it does not hit the Jquery code. Also I want to hit the controller after this code   `var raceName = '@Url.Action("RacesName", "Races")?id=' + race;`.

Please guide me if I am doing anything wrong. Thank you.

Parent View

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-body">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, new List<SelectListItem>
                  {

                    new SelectListItem {Value = "PER", Text = "Peru" },
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "SAF", Text="South Africa" },

                  },
                    new { @id = "CountryList", @class = "form-control" })

            <div id="mypartial"> </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Script to execute the partial

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
           var route = '@Url.Action("PartialView", "Stakes")';
              route = encodeURI(route);
               $('#mypartial').load(route);
        });
```

Controller to load Partial

```
  public ActionResult PartialView(string countrylist, ClsStakesRaces clsStakesRaces)
        {
            if(countrylist==null)
            {
                clsStakesRaces.Country = "PER";
            }
            else
            {
                clsStakesRaces.Country = countrylist;
            }

            StakesRacesDetails stakesRacesDetails = new StakesRacesDetails();
           return PartialView("~/Views/Stakes/_PartialStakes.cshtml", stakesRacesDetails.StacksRacesList(clsStakesRaces.Country));

        }
```

This is the script which I want to execute when I click on `linkClass`

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myform').on('click', '.linkClass', function () {
                debugger;
                var race = $(this).data("raceid");
                var raceName = '@Url.Action("RacesName", "Races")?id=' + race;
                 $(this).load(raceName);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Partial View

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="myform">
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Date)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Race)</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)

                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="linkClass" type="button" data-raceid="@item.RaceId">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Race)</button>

                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: What do you mean _pass button value from partial to parent view_? You code is loading a partial view by calling a controller method (and you have not shown your `RacesName(int id)` method, or what it returns. Its also not clear why you are replacing your `<table>` element

Comment: @StephenMuecke, ` $('#myform').on('click', '.linkClass', function () {` is not hitting. I want to pass value of` raceid` into controller.

Comment: Do you have jquery loaded? What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I am not getting any error either. How to check whether JQuery is loaded or not.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, If I place the  JQuery code in the partial then it executes but not in the parent view.

Comment: You would be getting an error if it was not loaded. The code you have shown works fine. Are you generating the `<table>` element after the initial page has loaded? (and scripts should not be in partials)

Comment: Yes Stephen, I am generating `<table>` element after initial page load. It's weird, I am not getting any error.

Comment: You did not answer my question. How is the that `<table>` element loaded in the main view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have edited my question where I have added parent view and how the partial loads. Please have a look and provide me the way to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the `<table id="myform">` element after the initial view has been loaded, therefore you need to use event delegation using the `.on()` function. While you are using `.on()`, you are using it on the wrong element - it needs to be applied to an element that exists in the DOM when the page is first loaded.

Change the script to use the `<div id="mypartial">` element

```
$('#mypartial').on('click', '.linkClass', function () {
    debugger;
    var race = $(this).data("raceid");
    var raceName = '@Url.Action("RacesName", "Races")?id=' + race;
     $(this).load(raceName); // modify as required
});
```

Comment: One small help related to this question. can you please advice me why `raceName` is not hitting the controller.

Comment: You have not shown the `RacesNames()` method in `RacesController` :)  - suggest you ask a new question with the relevant details (and any errors you are getting)

Comment: I have added new question. Please have a look  and suggest me. Thank you.